# Empty CreatorDate field in PDF files generated by Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, pdf, itext, oraclereports

There is some issues for the PDF which are generated by Oracle reports. Below are the first few lines if we open in text editor. Here CreatorDate doesn't have close bracket. Due to this its not opening in iText, Is there any way to fix the PDF and open it.

```
%PDF-1.1
1 0 obj
<<
/Creator (Developer 2000)
/CreatorDate (
/Author (Oracle Reports)
/Producer (Oracle PDF driver)
/Title (con5010Cr41201412990620141001111044.pdf)
>>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to fix the PDF and open it.

You can patch it by replacing the characters on the line

```
/CreatorDate (
```

by space characters.